# Linking dynamically created text boxes and labels

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic

I created an array of of TextBoxes and an array of Labels. When the information is updated in the TextBox I want it to change the Labels. How would I be able to do this? Below is piece of my code. I have not created the EvenHandler that I think is the part I need help with. All in C# using windows application form.

```
textBoxes = new TextBox[value];
labels = new Label[value];

for (int i = 1; i < value; i++)
{
    textBoxes[i] = new TextBox();
    textBoxes[i].Location = new Point(30, ToBox.Bottom + (i * 43));

    labels[i] = new Label(); 
    labels[i].Location = new Point(TopBox3[i].Width + 140, TopBox3[i].Top +3);

    textboxes[i].ValueChanged += new EventHandler(this.TextBox_ValueChanged) ;

    this.Controls.Add(labels[i]);
    this.Controls.Add(textBoxes[i]);
}
```

Comment: There is no ValueChanged event for TextBox - it's TextChanged.

Answer (score 1):

You can remember the index of the TextBox in the Tag property

```
 textBoxes[i].Tag = i;
```

and then use this value in your eventhandler to get the corresponding label (assuming that you hold the labels array as a local variable)

```
protected void TextBox_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  TextBox textbox = sender as TextBox;
  if(textbox==null)
    return;
  int index = Convert.ToInt32(textbox.Tag);
  if(index >= 0 && index < this.labels.Length)
  {
    Label label = this.labels[index];
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write something like this:

```
    private void textBox1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox changedTxt = sender as TextBox;
        for (int i = 1; i < value; i++)
            if (textBoxes[i] == changedTxt)
            {
                Label lblToChange = labeld[i];
                lblToChange.Text = changedTxt.Text;
                break;
            }
    }
```

In the method the TextBox whose text has changed is passed as "sender". You look into your array for it, so you identify the index "i" which can be used to access the corresponding Label and to set its text.

BTW as Tim said, the event is TextChanged, not ValueChanged. Furthermore be aware that the event is triggered for every change in the text, i.e. as soon as you press a key the label will be updated. If you prefer to update your labels only when the user has finished to enter its text Leave is the event you should use.